# Spring 4 MVC Form: Create Object with list of sub objects

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I looking for help in understanding how to create a new object through a form which has the user select multiple sub-objects (which will come pre-populated) and available to select with a checkbox.

**OrderController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/order" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String order(ModelMap model) {

    List<Exam> exams = examService.findAllExams();
    List<Document> documents = documentService.findAllDocuments();

    model.addAttribute("exams", exams);
    model.addAttribute("documents", documents);

    return "order"; // jsp page reference
}
```

**Order.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"order\"")
    public class Order implements Serializable
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id 
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "order_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private Integer id;

        @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
        @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
        @Column(name = "uuid", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private String uuid;

        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        @Column(name = "order_date", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private Date orderDate;

        @Column(name="order_status", nullable=false)
        private String orderStatus;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
        private User user;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "order")
        private Set<OrderExam> orderExams = new HashSet<OrderExam>(0);

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "order")
        private Set<OrderDocument> orderDocuments = new HashSet<OrderDocument(0); 

        //getters & setters
    }
```

**OrderExam.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="order_exam")
public class OrderExam implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "order_exam_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
    private Order order;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "exam_id", nullable = false)
    private Exam exam;

    @Column(name="exam_amount", nullable=true)
    private Integer examAmount;

    @Column(name="answer_sheet_amount", nullable=true)
    private String answerSheetName;

    @Column(name="students_per_csv", nullable=true)
    private String studentsPerCSV;

    @Column(name="pas", nullable=true)
    private Boolean pearsonAnswerSheet;

    //getters & setters
}
```

**Exam.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="exam")
public class Exam implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "exam_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="name", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="code", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String code;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "exam")
    private Set<OrderExam> exams = new HashSet<OrderExam>(0);

     //getters & setters
}
```

As you can see I am passing in a list of exams and documents which will populate a form with available options (can be seen in the image below (**exams anyway**)). The user needs to be able to select multiple rows, so that a single order has multiple exams and documents associated to it.

[image: OrderForm:Exams]

My order.jsp is a little much to post the entire thing here but here is the part I have which is displayed in the image above.

**Order.jsp**

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="order" class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
```

```
<c:forEach items="${exams}" var="exam">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th scope="row"><input type="checkbox" class="flat"></th>
                                                    <td><input id="middle-name" type="text" name="middle-name" readonly="readonly" value="${exam.name} - ${exam.code}" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"></td>
                                                    <td><input id="middle-name" type="text" name="middle-name" value="0" class="form-control col-md-3 col-xs-12"></td>
                                                    <td><input id="middle-name" type="text" name="middle-name" value="0" class="form-control col-md-3 col-xs-12"></td>
                                                    <td><input id="middle-name" type="text" name="middle-name" value="0" class="form-control col-md-3 col-xs-12"></td>
                                                    <c:choose>
                                                        <c:when test="${exam.name == 'Algebra 2 (Common Core)'}">
                                                            <th scope="row"><input type="checkbox" class="flat"></th>
                                                        </c:when>
                                                        <c:otherwise>
                                                            <th scope="row"></th>
                                                        </c:otherwise>
                                                    </c:choose>
                                                </tr>
                                            </c:forEach>
<!-- Other Stuff Goes Here -->
</form:form>
```

So in short, would someone be willing to show me how to set up the form in the way I described above? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit broad however you could try this as below. I have only covered exams. Principal for documents will be the same.

You will need a couple of new classes to capture the submitted form inputs:

**Order Form to Capture Selections**

```
public class OrderForm{

    private List<ExamWrapper> allAvailableExams = new ArrayList<>();

    private XOptionPrintWrapper selectedWrapper;

    public OrderForm(){

    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

**Exam Wrapper : Decorates an Exam with a 'selected' property**

```
public class ExamWrapper{

    private boolean selected;
    private Exam exam;

    public ExamWrapper(Exam exam){
        this.exam = exams;
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

**Change Contoller to**

```
public class OrderController{

    //Exams model populated by the method below
    //moved as we also need it populated on POST
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/order" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String order(ModelMap modelMap) {

        //only needed on GET so put in model here
        List<XOptionPrintWrapper> availableWrappers = //someList;
        modelMap.put("availableWrappers", availableWrappers);

        return "order"; 
    }

    //handles for submit
    //model atribute is automatically populated by the framework
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/order" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String order(@ModelAttribute("orderForm") OrderForm orderForm) {

        //process selected exams

        return "nextView"; 
    }

    //on get populates the initial model for display
    //on post create an instance which the form params will be bound to
    @ModelAttribute("orderForm")
    public OrderForm getOrderForm(){
        OrderForm orderForm = new OrderForm();
        List<Exam> exams = examService.findAllExams();

        for(Exam exam : exams){
            orderForm.getAllAvailableExams.add(new ExamWrapper(exam));
        }

        return orderForm;
    }
}
```

**In JSP use Sping support for binding to indexed properties:**

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="orderForm" class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
    <c:forEach items="${orderForm.allAvailableExams}" var="exam" varStatus="status">
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><input name="allAvailableExams[${status.index}].selected" 
                     type="checkbox" class="flat"></th>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>

        <form:select path="selectedWrapper">
        <form:options items="${availableWrappers}" 
               itemValue="somePropertyOfXOptionPrintWrapper " 
               itemLabel="somePropertyOfXOptionPrintWrapper " />
        </form:select>
</form>
```

I obviously haven't been able to try all of this but think it should all be okay.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alan, I'll give this a shot and let you know how it works out.

Comment: What did you want to know?

Comment: In the same form, I need to populate a dropdown list, and allow the user to select one option, and post it back with the rest of the info. How would I set this up with the code you provided above?

Comment: I tried to add a "private List<XOptionPrintWrapper> allAvailableOptionPrints = new ArrayList<>();" to the form, similarly to the OrderForm class. I populated it like you did in the getOrderForm method. But when it comes to getting the data to post, I guess I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: See updates to GET method in Controller, OrderForm and JSP form. To get this to work you will need to register a simple converter that will auto-convert the id of the selected form option to the relevant type (e.g. by database lookup). http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert

Comment: Thank you again! I'll take a look and try this out. Unfortunately I can only work on this project once a week, but once I try it out I'll be sure to let you know. :)